# What is the max number of fields a collection can have?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Is there a max number of fields that a collection can handle?
I have a collection that needs to support 300 fields (so each document will have 300 fields).

On those fields, only a couple will need to be indexed, as the other will never be searched.
So, I guess, indexing is not a limiting factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB documents has a document size limit of [16 MB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) and a 100 levels limit of nesting, but the documentation does not specified the fields limit. For the fastest processing, ensure that your [indexes fit entirely in RAM](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/index.html#ensure-indexes-fit-in-ram) so that the system can avoid reading the index from disk.

The data that is accessed together should be stored together, having that in mind you should considere thoses 300 fileds per documents.